# Better form processing - multiple dates and selection issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm having a bit of trouble, conceptually and programmatically with a form.

The user can choose one or more (as many as they like) of specific dates within a large amount of dates. I don't want a checkbox for each date. I've looked at some datepickers (jquery, mootools) but I've not found one that a) only allows weekdays, b) allows certain dates to be knocked off, c) allows selection of one or more, d) allows the user to be fed a price based on how many dates they chose. I need to have the data accessible through javascript, so I can feed it to the "review" part of my form before submission to a php/mysql database.

I need not only a link to a tool that'll allow this (if you know of one of course), but I also need to know how to implement it in this way and if you can suggest one - maybe an alternative way of processing this form.

Apologies for my rather frank way of requesting help, but my stress levels are rising rapidly about this.

Thanks for any help you can give

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I quickly realised (with the help of jondavidjohn) that my requirements were way off, there wouldn't be a pre-made customisable javascript (perhaps JQuery) module that would allow this. I resorted to checkbox groups, it's not the most revolutionary treatment but it works

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like (with the very specific functionality you need), you need to author your own jquery plugin/extention to handle this.

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring

You might investigate what it would take to simply extend the jQuery UI Datepicker, as it seems like they have done the heavy lifting for you, and just add the functionality you need.

http://jqueryui.com/development

Comment: I don't have the luxury of time to learn how to author my own plugin, I was hoping somebody could help me with modifying the UI Datepicker.

Comment: Well, you're basically asking someone to write a very specific piece of software for you, you might make a posting on http://careers.stackoverflow.com